# Using http protocol between servers

Tags: security, http, protocols, intranet

I have a configuration of two servers working in intranet.
First one is a web server that produces html pages to the browser, this html sends requests to the second server, which produces and returns reports (also html) according to some GET parameter's value.
Since this solution is un-secured (the passed parameter is exposed) I thought about having the html (produced by the first server) sending the requests for report back to the first server, there, a security check will be made, and the request for report will be sent to the reports server using http between the servers, instead of from browser to server.
The report's markup will be returned to the first server (as a string?), added to the response object and presented in the browser.
Is this a common practice of http?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a common practice. In fact, it works the same when your webserver needs to fetch some data from a database (not publically exposed - ie not in the webserver DMZ for example).

But you need to be able to use dynamic page generation (not static html. Let's suppose your webserver allows PHP or java for example).

- your page does the equivalent of an HTTP GET (or POST, or whatever you like) do your second server, sending any required parameter you need. You can use cURL libraries, or fopen(http://), etc.
- it receives the result, checks the return code, can also do optionnal content manipulation (like replacing some text or URLs)
- it sends back the result to the user's browser.

If you can't (or won't) use dynamic page generation, you can configure your webserver to proxy some requests to the second server (for example with Apache's mod_proxy).

For example, when a request comes to server 1 for URL "http://server1/reports", the webserver proxies a request to "http://server2/internal/reports?param1=value1&param2=value2&etc".

The user will get the result of "http://server2/internal/reports?param1=value1&param2=value2&etc", but will never see from where it comes (from his point of view, he only knows http://server1/reports).
You can do more complex manipulations associating proxying with URL rewriting (so you can use some parameters of the request to server1 on the request to server2).

If it's not clear enough, don't hesitate to give more details (o/s, webserver technology, urls, etc) so I can give you more hints.

Answer (score 0):

Two others options:

1. Configure the Internet facing HTTP server with a proxy (e.g.
   mod_proxy in Apache)
2. Leave the server as it is and add an Application Firewal